# Registering Internet Explorer tool bands

Tags: internet-explorer, winapi, com, toolbar, registration

I've created an Explorer tool band using ATL.  It implements the `IDeskBand`, `IPersistStream`, and `IObjectWithSite` interfaces.  And this is its registration file:

```
HKCR
{
    NoRemove CLSID
    {
        ForceRemove {7a63bbd9-8025-4d29-89fa-bdb9ededb604} = s 'Toolbar'
        {
            InprocServer32 = s '%MODULE%'
            {
                val ThreadingModel = s 'Apartment'
            }
            TypeLib = s '{7c8f6572-d30f-4958-a1c2-0202461dffa5}'
            Version = s '1.0'
        }
    }
}

HKLM
{
    NoRemove Software
    {
        NoRemove Microsoft
        {
            NoRemove 'Internet Explorer'
            {
                NoRemove Toolbar
                {
                    val '{7a63bbd9-8025-4d29-89fa-bdb9ededb604}' = s 'Toolbar'
                }               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The tool band is loaded up by File Explorer successfully, but it is not loaded by Internet Explorer.  Is there a reason why?  Interestingly enough, it's listed as an add-on in Internet Explorer's add-on manager.  But it's not available from the tool bar menu in IE.  I've reviewed the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//bb776819(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), but I can't discern what is needed to register an Internet Explorer tool band that isn't required for File Explorer.  Thank you for any info.

Comment: IE is practically dead, why even bother? I don't think any of this stuff is really supported any more.

Comment: Well I just installed the Google toolbar, and it still works.  But I can't figure out how its registration differs from the above.

Comment: Did you go to the View menu -> Explorer bars and see whether your tool is listed over there or not? If not, please check it. Please also inform us which version of the IE browser and which OS build you are using for this test?

Comment: Yes, I checked that location, but it's not there.  I'm using IE 11.0.9600.19678 on Windows 8.1.  I'm wondering if it has to do with registering as approved or with the right compatibility.

Comment: Can you please also share the detailed steps that you tried to implement the band? It can help us to make a test and see whether something needs to change or modify. the registration file is not giving much idea about the cause of the issue.